# Version number in Winform form text

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

How can I insert the assembly version number (which I set to auto increment) into a Winform form text?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Either of these will work:

```
var version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version; 
this.Text = String.Format("My Application Version {0}", version);

string version = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion; 
this.Text = String.Format("My Application Version {0}", version);
```

Assuming this is run on the `Form` you wish to display the text on

Comment: @Mikhael - If it's being run on the form itself like the OP then this reference will be added by default, but I'll add it for clarity in case it's being used somewhere else, thanks

Answer (score 25):

```
Text = Application.ProductVersion
```

Quick way to get the full version as a string (e.g. "1.2.3.4")

Answer (score 12):

I'm using the following in a WinForm:

```
public MainForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Version version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
  Text = Text + " " + version.Major + "." + version.Minor + " (build " + version.Build + ")"; //change form title
}
```

Not showing revision number to the user, build number is enough technical info

Make sure your AssemblyInfo.cs ends in the following (remove the version it has there by default) for VisualStudio to autoincrement build and revision number. You have to update major and minor versions yourself at every release (update major version for new features, minor version when you do just fixes):

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Comment: not sure if my edit got published, anyway can also use this modification:  Version version = (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)?
    ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion :
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    //if network deployed show published version (as the web install page does)

Answer (score 3):

its in the `System.Reflection.AssemblyName` class eg.

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

as you can see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version.aspx

```
class Example
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The version of the currently executing assembly is: {0}",
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);

        Console.WriteLine("The version of mscorlib.dll is: {0}",
            typeof(String).Assembly.GetName().Version);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fvi = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
return fvi.ProductVersion;
```

Answer (score 0):

To include application name and version the following one liner will do it:

```
Text = $"{Application.ProductName} {Application.ProductVersion}";
```